# Rails 5: How to set an object's attributes using link_to, without any controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to update an object titled Dog which has the attribute name. I wish to do so with using any controller methods, currently I am trying this:

`<%= link_to 'Delete Name', dog_path(@dog:{name: nil}), method: :patch %>`

This keeps giving me a syntax error but I've tried everything I can.

Also, I am aware that it is possible to define a function (in this case titled "delete_name") in the controller and use the following:

`<%= link_to 'Delete Name', controller: "dogs", action: "delete_name", id: @dog %>`

But I wish to use the first method. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you not following Rails's conventions with a simple `destroy` method in the controller?

Comment: `destroy` would delete the entire object whereas I would just like to delete its 'name' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Name', dog_path(@dog:{name: nil}), method: :patch %>
```

Does indeed have a syntax error. You have a @ before your hash key called dog. It should be:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Name', dog_path(dog:{name: nil}), method: :patch %>
```

You don't want to use the instance variable as the key for a hash, because that would set the value of the instance variable as the key. See this example:

```
2.3.3 :001 > @instance_variable = "test"
 => "test"
2.3.3 :002 > {@instance_variable => "value"}
 => {"test"=>"value"}
```

Comment: Thanks Kasper that worked! I assumed the dog hash key would have to follow the @dog object on the page. But since we have already specified the dog_path() it just knows how to look for the currently dog object that we are at?

Comment: You cannot use an instance variable that way. The key must always be a valid symbol when using ":". If you used rockets, then you could have used your instance variable, but then the key would be set to the value of the instance variable, which isn't what you want either.

I have updated my original answer, so that you can see an example of this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation Kasper that really helped!